# gae-sessions equivalent for Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, python-2.7

I wonder wether there's a port for gae-sessions (https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) for the "new" Python (2.7) on AppEngine.
Or any other comparable library.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't see any reason it wouldn't work on Python 2.7 as-is.

Comment: @NickJohnson because Python 2.7 on AppEngine uses webapp2 and not webapp, gae-sessions is made for webapp.

Comment: Reading the docs for gae-sessions, it's WSGI middleware, and doesn't appear to have anything webapp-specific in it. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using webapp2, it has sessions mechanism built-in:

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html